# Check if external activity opened successfully?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How do I check if an external activity in Settings has opened successfully? In this case, I want to check if `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` opened successfully.

Here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);                    
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: there is something like `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Yes, but how can it be used in my case?

Comment: May you can take help of `Activity` lifecycle. If another `Activity` is opened successfully then `onPause()` in our first activity will be called.

Comment: @cgb_pandey Can you give me an implementation for my cas as an answer?

Comment: I am added my answer. It is just a workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
    // No Activity found that can handle this intent. 
}
else{
    // There is an activity which can handle this intent. 
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the activity exists but it simply doesn't open for some reason. This happens in some Huawei devices. I tested your code already. So, your code doesn't solve this issue unfortunately.

Comment: In that case does the call to `startActivity()` throw an `ActivityNotFoundException`? Do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: My users are not experiencing any crashes so it's probably not an ActivityNotFoundException. Also, the activity does exist but it simply doesn't open on some Huawei devices.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to hack-fix a possible bug with Huawei's EMUI. Even if you could detect that the activity didn't open, what would you do?

Comment: @Sharp I would show a pop up, explaining what steps need to be done in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use some `boolean` flag variable to check whether or not we should be listening to `onPause()` lifecycle event of the current `Activity`.
Then, we can check the value of this flag variable inside the `onPause()`. If it's true then it's more likely that it is called because the next `Activity` is opened successfully. A sample `Activity` may look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // a boolean variable to check whether or not another activity is opened or not
    // if opened our this activity will be paused
    private boolean externalActivityOpened = false;

    // a boolean variable to filter all other condition due to which our activity
    // can be paused
    private boolean startLookingIfCurrentActivityIsPaused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        openLocationSettings();
    }

    private void openLocationSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        // set variable to true...if activity is paused now, there is high chance
        // that it is paused because the location settings has been opened
        startLookingIfCurrentActivityIsPaused = true;
        // this solution will fail if at this very point the interruption occurs such as a phone call
        // other than that it should work fine I guess xD
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // we check to see if onpause is called after we wanted to start the location settings
        // if yes then it is almost certain that the new activity has been started
        if (startLookingIfCurrentActivityIsPaused) {
            externalActivityOpened = true;
            startLookingIfCurrentActivityIsPaused = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "New activity has been started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method can easily fail unfortunately. I'd prefer another better way.

Comment: maybe you can try to start the `intent` with `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` and then see if it returns successfully in `onActivityResult()` or the newer `ActivityContracts` way.

Comment: Please explain that in detail by editing your answer